# Why did Maria rub badger fat on Darusya's head?

Tags: ukrainian-language, maria-matios, sweet-darusya

In chapter 2 of *Sweet Darusya*, Maria rubbed badger fat on Darusya's head and put a cabbage leaf on top of that in an apparent effort to help with her headaches. Why did she do that?

Comment: Badger fat - they say it's good for _all_ medical problems, try google translate https://www.apteka.ua/article/160188

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Badger fat is a common folk medicine in eastern Europe.  It is typically used to treat cuts or burns, though a close friend from Voronezh reports having been given hot badger fat to drink to treat sore throat.  Cabbage leaves are commonly used to treat headache.  A small academic survey of Belarusian remedies, including these, can be found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5627493/).